# Which way is correct: "to shuffle cards" or "to muddle up the cards"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

What way is correct in English:

"to shuffle cards" or "to muddle up the cards"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "muddle up" the cards in an old fashioned card index because the cards in the index have to be in the right order for the index to be useful. In the case of playing cards they are *supposed* to be in a random order for the game to be played. You do this by "shuffling" them. "Muddling up" something is never a good thing so the difference is in the intention.

Answer (score 4):

Just "shuffle" (not "shuffle up") is the idiomatic way to say you have mixed a deck of playing cards in preparation for a game or card trick:

> I have shuffled the cards.

"Muddled up" can mean a different kind of "mixed up" - it can mean *confused*.

Comment: The OP does say "shuffle cards", I don't see any  "shuffle up" in the question.

Comment: You can shuffle things **around**, but the expression is not used with playing cards when the intention is to place them in a random order, e.g. prior to playing. That's just shuffling.

Comment: *Shuffle up the cards* is also an idiomatic way to say it though. (There are other verbs where adding *up* doesn’t really change the meaning, as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4284/41273) for example.)